# Receiving error “name.split is not a function” in IBM BPM Dojo CoachView

Tags: javascript, dojo

I get an error `name.split is not a function` in IBM BPM Dojo on line below.

```
_context.binding.get("value").get(i).set("expectedDeliveryDate", e.newVal);
```

The list has 3 items and `i` is the index number in iterating. Field `e.newVal` is a non-empty string (verified with console logs).

Answer (score 0):

.split is not available on number. Maybe IBM BPM do split on 'get' parameter

```
_context.binding.get("value").get(i.toString()).set("expectedDeliveryDate", e.newVal);
```